# Django Side Bar Text Wont Appear

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

so I am trying to Add Another Side Bar Text On my Website Called "Create" But It Only Shows The "Home" I created Not The Views At All [IMAGE](https://gyazo.com/4bbd4c34bb5a881e5f9d4b57e2af8416) still learning how to make website but learning little by little not sure why I am having this problem

sidenav1 is my Create Text And Sidenav is my Home Page Text

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .sidenav {
            height:15%;
            width:1600;
            position: fixed;
            z-index:1;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background-color:#2C3E50;
            overflow-x: :hidden;
            padding-top:20px;
        }
        .sidenav a {
            padding:6px 8px 16px 676px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #2ECC71;
            display:block;

        }

        .sidenav1 a {
            padding:6px 6px 16px 696px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #2ECC71;
            display:block;

        }


        .sidenav a:hover{
            color:#f1f1f1;

        }
        .main{
            margin-left:60px;
            padding: 0px 10px;
        }

        .sidenav1 a {
            padding:6px 8px 16px 676px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #2ECC71;
            display:block;
        }       

    </style>
    <title>{% block title %} Habibs Website {% endblock %}</title>

</head>

</body>


<div class="sidenav">
    <a herf="/home">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="sidenav1">
    <a herf="/create">Create</a>
</div>

<div class="sidenav2">
    <a herf="/2">View</a>
</div>





<div id= "content", name="content", class="main">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .nav-wrapper {
            z-index:1;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background-color:#2C3E50;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding: 20px 0px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .nav-wrapper div {
            margin: 0px 20px;
        }
        .nav-wrapper a {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size:25px;
            color: #2ECC71;
            display:block;
        }
        .nav-wrapper a:hover{
            color:#f1f1f1;
        }
        .main{
            margin-left:60px;
            padding: 0px 10px;
        }

    </style>
    <title>{% block title %} Habibs Website {% endblock %}</title>

</head>

</body>

<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="sidenav">
        <a herf="/home">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div class="sidenav1">
        <a herf="/create">Create</a>
    </div>

    <div class="sidenav2">
        <a herf="/2">View</a>
    </div>
</div>




<div id= "content", name="content", class="main">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like this.

[image]